# Laravel 5.6:Resource not loading on one route

Tags: php, html, laravel, resources

I'm using a pre-loader gif in my layout which is placed in public/img and being used through the following line of code:
`<img src="img/preloader.gif" alt="Preloader">`

This works perfectly fine for all routes except one, said route is defined as follows:

```
Route::get('/test/{name}', function ($name) {
return view('test')->with('name',$name); });
```

Here is the 'test' view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<section>
    <div>
        <h1>{{$name}}</h1>  
    </div>
</section>

@endsection
```

Lastly, here's my slightly modified filesystems.php in which 'local' was changed:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('../public/img/uploads/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],

];
```

Why am i facing this problem and what is the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image src is using something called a **relative URI**, which essentially says "take the current URI, and add this to the end of it".

When you are on your homepage `example.com`, your image path is `example.com/img/preloader.gif`, which is correct.

Once you're on a deeper URI with more than one segment, e.g. `example.com/test/foobar`, the image URI becomes `example.com/test/img/preloader.gif` which is obviously incorrect.

The easiest and most recommended way to address this in Laravel is to use the [`asset()` or `secure_asset()` helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset). This will help generate an absolute URI to the image/asset, and will be correct regardless of which page of your app the user is on.

```
<img src="{!! asset('img/preloader.gif') !!}" alt="Preloader">
```

Comment: What you've explained makes perfect sense, now after making the requisite changes, the gif preloader resource loads (although it's loop doesn't stop, i'll look into that). Thanks for solving the issue.